# The Open from Source Control operation ... then Visual Studio opens up latest from source safe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

When I open a project in Visual Studio I get the following dialog box message:

The Open from Source Control operation is still in progress but you can start working now. The rest of the projects will be retrieved asynchinously.

Then it gets the latest from soruce safe, overwriting what ever I had. How do I stop VS2010 / source safe from doing this

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that you enabled "Get everything when a solution or project is opened" at Visual Studio Tools->Options->Source Control->Evironment. If so, uncheck it and then try again.

Comment: I have noticed this answer else were on the web but it didn't fix this issue. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I stoped visual from doing this by deleting *.vssscc and mssccprj.scc

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and when nothing else worked I simply removed source control related lines from solution file of my project. In my case it was a section in .sln file starting with line

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
```

Note: once you do this you have to manually connect with your relevant versioning system.